# Dyanmic datatype in a structure

Tags: arduino

I've defined some data structures that implement a register protocol for a Modbus/RS-485 application.  I'm compiling this for a Particle electron board.

How do I add a varying datatype to a structure?  I tried *(void*) as well.  Is this even possible?

```
    typedef struct {
        uint16_t registerAddress;
        uint8_t  registerSize;
        void*  dataType;
        char  description[50];
    } _rgRegister;

    static const _rgRegister PressureParameterRegister[6]={
      {0x038, 2, float, "Measured value"},
      {0x040, 1, ushort, "Parameter Id = 2 (pressure)"},
      {0x041, 1, ushort, "Units Id"},
      {0x042, 1, ushort, "Data Quality Id"},
      {0x043, 2, float, "Off line sentinel value (default = 0.0)"},
      {0x045, 1, char, "Available Units = 0x0005"}
    };
```

The other option is I declare it as:

```
char datatype[10];
```

and pass it as:

```
_rgRegister.datatype = "float"
```

And I have to have some switch statement that dynamically casts the datatype to the data.

Comment: you can use `auto` keyword to automatically assign data type to variables at runtime.

Comment: Or you can determine datatype at runtime using C++ `typeid->name()` function too.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I add a varying datatype to a structure? I tried (void) as well. Is this even possible?

If the data type is limited, you can use an `enum` to represent the data type and a `union` to represent the data.

```
enum DataType { DT_CHAR, DT_USHORT, DT_INT, DT_FLOAT, ..., };

typedef struct {
    uint16_t registerAddress;
    uint8_t  registerSize;
    DataType  dataType;
    union 
    {
       char  c;
       unsigned short us;
       int   i;
       float f;
       ...
    } data;
    char  description[50];
} _rgRegister;

static const _rgRegister PressureParameterRegister[6]={
  {0x038, 2, DT_FLOAT, 0,  "Measured value"},
  {0x040, 1, DT_USHORT, 0, "Parameter Id = 2 (pressure)"},
  {0x041, 1, DT_USHORT, 0, "Units Id"},
  {0x042, 1, DT_USHORT, 0, "Data Quality Id"},
  {0x043, 2, DT_FLOAT, 0, "Off line sentinel value (default = 0.0)"},
  {0x045, 1, DT_CHAR, 0, "Available Units = 0x0005"}
};
```

If you have the option of using `boost`, you can use [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/any.html) to simplify your code.